# Perl CGI open fuction knowledge

Tags: perl, function, cgi

I've read about perl cgi, but i don't understand `open(HAIR,"hair".$q->param('Hair'));`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI;

$q = new CGI;
if ( defined( $q->param('Head') ) ) {
    print $q->header( -type => 'image/bmp' );
    open( HEAD,  "head" . $q->param('Head') );
    open( HAIR,  "hair" . $q->param('Hair') );
    open( NOSE,  "nose" . $q->param('Nose') );
    open( MOUTH, "mouth" . $q->param('Mouth') );
    open( EYES,  "eyes" . $q->param('Eyes') );

    while ( read( HEAD, $headb, 1 ) ) {
        read( HAIR,  $hairb,  1 );
        read( NOSE,  $noseb,  1 );
        read( MOUTH, $mouthb, 1 );
        read( EYES,  $eyesb,  1 );
        print( chr( ord($headb) & ord($hairb) & ord($noseb) & ord($mouthb) & ord($eyesb) ) );
    }
}
```

I only see open function like `open(FileHandle, filename)`, so what is `.$q->param('Nose')`?

Comment: CGI->param() gets the form or query variable sent to the webpage; eg with http://example.com/?head=abc $q->param('head') will be 'abc'.

Comment: `print "hair".$q->param('Hair');` perhaps? And regarding `open()` paractices => http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2010/04/three-arg-open-migrating-to-modern-perl.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so let's look at this logically. You know that `open` calls look like this:

```
open(FileHandle, filename)
```

And you have an open call that looks like this:

```
open(HEAD,"head".$q->param('Head'));
```

Parameters are separated by commas, so it's simple enough to untangle this. `HEAD` is the filehandle and `"head".$q->param('Head')` is the filename.

The `.` in that is the concatenation operator. So the filename is going to be the string "head" followed by the result of the expression `$q->param('Head')`. `$q` is your CGI object (created from the `$q = new CGI` line above and `->` is how we call methods on objects in Perl. You can look up the `param` method in the [CGI](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI) documentation. You'll find that it gives you the value of the CGI parameter of the given name. So `$q->param('Head')` gives you a string containing whatever the "Head" parameter contains in the CGI request and you filename is the string "head" followed by that value.

It's worth pointing out that this code has a few issues that should be fixed. To list some of the most obvious.

1. All Perl code should contain `use strict` and `use warnings`. This will then mean that you need to declare all of your variables (probably using `my`).
2. The line `$q = new CGI` uses an outdated and potentially problematic syntax called "Indirect Object Syntax". It's far better to use the direct object version - `$q = CGI->new`.
3. Your filehandles are all global strings (HEAD, HAIR, etc). Far better to use lexical variables for filehandles - `open(my $head, "head".$q->param('Head'))`.
4. It is safer to explicitly set the file mode using the three-arg version of `open` - `open(my $head, '<', "head".$q->param('Head'))`.
5. You should check the return value from `open` and take appropriate action if it is false.
6. It is dangerous to take user input (like your `param` calls) and use it directly in filenames.

Comment: Can you tell me more about      while (read(HEAD,$headb,1))     , so what is true-condition

Comment: If you have a separate question it's probably worth starting a completely new discussion. But perhaps see if [the documentation for read](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/read.html) helps first.

Comment: @user3600331 A note regarding the points 3 & 5: Without an explicit open mode, this code is very susceptible to shell injection, e.g. with a parameter of `; echo pwned |` (the trailing pipe makes Perl evaluate that code in a shell). And instead of `echo`, an attacker would use something more destructive such as `rm -rf .`